# Rowspan/colspan problem

Tags: html

I want to span the header of my table to 2 columns(2 td s) and to 2 rows(2 tr s). I tried using rowspan and colspan together, but it doesnot work for me. The header doesnot have anything written in it. It just colored background. Codes I wrote is as follows

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "0"  border= "0">
<tr valign = "top"><th colspan = "2" rowspan = "2"  Style="background:#FCE14E"></th></tr>
```

Can I find an alternative for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are confusing the purpose of the table head tag. Can you write more about what the end product is for (i.e. what else will go in the table head, what will be in the table, etc.)

Comment: Having problems with HTML in a JSP file doesn't make it a JSP problem. It's just a view technology producing/generating HTML code. Your problem is all about the generated HTML code. So I removed the JSP tag.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the comment. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colspan` should work. The `rowspan` is pointless here. The cell already covers the entire row. You cannot add another row to fill the remaining columns (because there are no remaining columns). You'd like to specify the `height` instead.

Here's the improved example:

```
<th colspan="2" style="height: 2em; background: #FCE14E;">&nbsp;</th>
```

Note that I added a `&nbsp;` (non breaking space) because the cell would otherwise not render in MSIE browser. Also note that you should prefer using CSS classes above inline styles using `style`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I needed to give the height:1em. The colspan alone was working for me, but the height was not the size of a row as it did not have any header. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more of your markup?  You'll need to have multiple rows and columns before this works well.  This might be closer:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th rowspan = 2 colspan = 2>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Column Header B should end up filling 2 rows and 2 columns, pushing E below C when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put any text in the header tage, so no text will be displayed (unless you are using script to add the text).

```
<th colspan = "2" rowspan = "2" Style="background:#FCE14E">Table header text goes here</th>
```